# lightbox plus reload after loading content ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, lightbox, reload, zooming

http://serennz.sakura.ne.jp/toybox/lightbox/

How to get the script to work on new elements loaded by ajax?

This code works, but after loading does not work zooming. ;/

```
var lightbox = new Lightbox({
        loadingimg:'resource/loading.gif',
        expandimg:'resource/expand.gif',
        shrinkimg:'resource/shrink.gif',
        blankimg:'resource/blank.gif',
        previmg:'resource/prev.gif',
        nextimg:'resource/next.gif',
        closeimg:'resource/close.gif',
        /*effectimg:'resource/zzoop.gif',*/
        effectpos:{x:-40,y:-20},
        effectclass:'effectable',
        resizable:true,
        animation:true
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your Ajax is working fine and you successfully get some html data. It will be like this:

```
$.get('ajax/more_pictures.html', function(data) {
  displayNewImages(data);
});
```

Now you add your new images into some container , and give them "`lightbox`" attributes:

```
function displayNewImages(images){
  $("#images_container").html(images);
  $("#images_container").find("a").attr("rel" , "lightbox").addClass("effectable");
}
```

And after all this create `Lightbox` instance :

```
var lightbox = new Lightbox({ 
  // all the rest
});
```

That's it , simply adding `rel="lightbox"` and `class="effectable"` attributes  to `a` element that wrapping image , and you're done!

Comment: have ajax code to load the data, but after reading the data script-lightbox does not work to end as it should. Zoom does not work. ~~in no way helped.

Comment: @magu112 update your question with a full code . it is good to see your Ajax call function

Comment: works ok :) will be easier to apply in this code?

Test CODE: [test code](http://wklej.to/Y5q5N/text)
 // 
[~~ajax load 1](http://wklej.to/2iMf4/text)
 // 

[~~~ajax load 2](http://wklej.to/n2HOj/text)
 // 
~~itd ajax load.....

Answer (score 0):

You need add this snippet after load images:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[data-toggle]').forEach((el) => el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const lightbox = new Lightbox(el);
  lightbox.show();
}));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.